# after adding html blocks using ajax, animation(jquery) does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

if you add this block forcibly, then everything works. my searches led me to the fact that when clicking on input, the focused is-focused classes are not added to it. 1 screenshot - how it works if you add html forcibly, 2 screenshot - how it works after loading using ajax
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

```
<html>
<div class="container-fluid py-4 contents">
    </div>
 <script src="../assets/js/core/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../assets/js/core/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/material-dashboard.min.js?v=3.1.0"></script>
  <script src="../assets/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../assets/js/plugins/smooth-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../assets/js/plugins/chartjs.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Github buttons -->
  <script async defer src="https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js"></script>

  <script>
async function Send_ajax(data,dataType,url){
   var result ="";
 try {
       
    $.ajax({
        url:url, //url  (action_ajax_form.php)
        type:"POST",
        async:false,
        data:data,  
        dataType: dataType, // 
        success:function(data){ 
        result = data;
},
        error: function(response) { // Данные не отправлены
           result= response;
        }
         
    });
   
  } catch(error) {
    // handle error, set some error state, display error toast, etc...
    result= error;
  }
  return result;
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
    Send_ajax("","html","../php/admin/get_config_form.php").then((result) => {
     $(".contents").html(result)
     });
      });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You for sure need to put the jQuery js BEFORE the other JS files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your problem description, the issue seems to be that you have an animation to run and the animation is at least partially implemented in Javascript, attaching some events to your HTML elements.

Now, if your HTML is present at page load, then your events are properly attached to it and therefore your animation properly runs, whereas, if you get your HTML via AJAX and then

```
$(".contents").html(result)
```

then the HTML structure is properly added to your container, but the Javascript events are not attached as you expected. To solve this issue, you will need to identify what events your animation needs to run, separate the definition of these events into a functionality to be executed and then make sure that you run that function after you changed the HTML based on result.

Alternatively, if you know the structure beforehand and the only difference in possible responses is the value of some fields, then you can refactor your approach so, instead of HTML structure, you would receive a JSON in your response and change the values of your fields rather than the structure, so you will not have to bother (re)attaching your event handlers.

Finally, it's also possible that your hard-coded structure is different in some manners than the one you receive in AJAX, so you will need to carefully compare the structure that you hard-coded earlier with the one you receive as AJAX response and fix the differences.